# In numpy, how to compare all values in an axis

Tags: python, numpy

For a numpy array, how can I change the value only if all elements along an axis are equal to another array? For example...

```
array = np.array([[1, 0, 1],
                  [0, 0, 1],
                  [1, 1, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0],
                  [1, 0, 1]])
```

I want to replace all `[1, 0, 1]` with `[1, 1, 1]`... so that `array` becomes

```
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

When I use a boolean array, it checks each individual number. How can I compare the entire row at once instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with:

```
array[(array == [1, 0, 1]).all(axis=1)] = [1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Your array, and search array:

```
In [87]: arr = np.array([[1, 0, 1], 
    ...:                   [0, 0, 1], 
    ...:                   [1, 1, 0], 
    ...:                   [0, 0, 0], 
    ...:                   [1, 0, 1]])                                                  
In [88]: x = np.array([1,0,1])
```

WIth a (5,3) and (3,) shape we can compare this with:

```
In [89]: arr == x                                                                       
Out[89]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
```

This makes use of broadcasting to treat the `x` as (1,3).  In other cases we may need to adjust the arrays for proper broadcasting.

And we can find the rows that match exactly, all True:

```
In [90]: (arr == x).all(axis=1)                                                         
Out[90]: array([ True, False, False, False,  True])
```

If we use that boolean array to index the first dimension of `arr`, we get the [1,0,1] rows:

```
In [96]: arr[(arr == x).all(axis=1)]                                                    
Out[96]: 
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1]])
```

and we can use the same indexing to replace the values of those rows (again this uses broadcasting to put a (3,) array into a (2,3) slot:

```
In [97]: arr[(arr == x).all(axis=1)]=[1,1,1]                                            
In [98]: arr                                                                            
Out[98]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

This is a good exercise in `numpy` broadcasting, indexing, and axis reduction.

Answer (score 0):

`np.sign()` should help you to compare an entire row to another.

```
np.sign([1,0,1] - [1,0,1])  # returns 0
```

It may be best to loop through your array checking `np.sign(array[i]-array[j])`.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html

Answer (score -1):

There is a built-in function in Numpy named `array_equal` which compares two arrays for equality. I think that is the function you want to use.

Here is the documentation of it: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your array contains only positive values, and you want to compare over the last axis you can do the following:

```
(a - a[..., [0]]).sum(-1) == 0
```